# php - how to stop server from sending emails

Tags: php

I made php command loop that send email forever

after close the web tab the server continuing sending me email

how can I stop it?

```
$x = 1;
while ($x == 1)
{

    echo date("d-m-Y ; H:i:s")."<br />";
    mail("reg@mail.com", "test  - ".date("d-m-Y ; H:i:s"), date("d-m-Y ; H:i:s"), "name@mail.com");

    sleep (60*60); // 30 min

}
```

Comment: On linux, find the process with `ps` and `kill` it. Under Windows, restart apache. for the next time use `set_time_limit()` to allow the script only run a given time or dont create an infinti loop with `while($x==1)` you are not doing anything with `$x` so it means `while(true)`

Comment: [`ignore_user_abort(false)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: 60*60 = 3600 seconds, which is 60 minutes